# Printing place values of a given number in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to print the place values of a given number in R, using below logic.

But when I ran the code it is rounding the value at some point and I couldn't able to understand the reason why? Can anyone please guide me understand the behavior here and suggest the fix? Thanks in advance.

```
Value <- 25080    
x <- 0L
print(paste("Actual Value = ", Value))    

while(Value > 0L){    
                  i <- round(Value) %% 10L    
                  print(paste("Place Value of ",i,i * (10 ** x)))    
                  Value <- round(Value / 10L,0L)    
                  x <- x + 1L    
                 }
```

Output: Actual Value is 25080, whereas if you check the output the 3-digit(in middle which is 0) is rounding to 1 in logic and output to 100.

```
[1] "Place Value of  0 0"

[1] "Place Value of  8 80"

**[1] "Place Value of  1 100"**

[1] "Place Value of  5 5000"

[1] "Place Value of  2 20000"
```

Comment: `Value <- round(Value/10L, 0L)` should be `Value <- floor(Value/10)`. It's rounding the 8 up to a 1 currently

Comment: Thanks a lot Allan. It's working fine.